# Child window opens and closes immediately

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am confused on how can I come with the solution for this. I have requirement like a have a link in my page(Parent Page) and clicking on that link will open up a new window(child page) with some details and then if I click on the parent window, the child window must get close. how can I do that. Here is what I tried.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function OpenWindow() {
               popupWindow = window.open('WebForm2.aspx', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
            }
            function closeWindow() {              
                popupWindow.close();
            }
        </script>
        <div id="daf" style="height: 100vh;" onclick="closeWindow()">           
              <a id="myLink" title="Click to do something" href="" onclick="OpenWindow();return false;">link text</a>
        </div>
```

but the problem I am facing is that the when I click the link the window is opened ans immediately its closed. this happens because the link inside the div. so clicking the link will fire both the functions. Please help me with solution

Thanks all!.. I got the soltuion from Niko. Here is what i was searching for

```
<div id="Div1" style="height: 100vh;" onclick="closeWindow()">           
    <a id="A1" href="#" onclick="OpenWindow(true)">link dtext</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstTime = false; // make use of temp variable
    function OpenWindow(k) {
        firstTime = k;
        popupWindow = window.open('WebForm2.aspx', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
    }
    function closeWindow() {
        if (firstTime == false) popupWindow.close();
        firstTime = false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @user27773448, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is you want but check this out, using a temp variable , You could achieve this.

passing a true value in a function call `openWindow(true)` and use of `firstTime` variable are the changes I have made.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var firstTime = false; // make use of temp variable

  function OpenWindow(k) {
       firstTime = k;
       popupWindow = window.open('WebForm2.aspx', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
  }
  function closeWindow(){
       if(firstTime == false)  popupWindow.close();
       firstTime=false;
  }

</script>

<div id="daf" style="height: 100vh;" onclick="closeWindow()">           
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="OpenWindow(true)">link text</a>
</div>
```

set the `firstTime` variable to true when you click on `link text` and when your closing the window, compare the value and change it to false for the next click.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline script:

```
<div id="daf" style="height: 100vh;">
```

and use (inside document ready handler?):

```
$('#daf').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.id === "myLink") return;
    closeWindow();
});
```

Comment: after removing "inline script" whats  daf

Comment: @user2773448 `<div id="daf"` !? Isn't it code you have posted??? By inline script i mean: ` onclick="closeWindow()"`, not removing the entire HTML tag